# How to keep the terminal updating while waiting for an input?

Tags: python, multithreading, input

I am making a chat server and want the chat to update live while you type instead of every time you press enter as the input is making my code hang.

Currently I have:

```
def send():
    message = input()
    #Send message

def receive():
    while unread_messages > 0:
        #Recive messages

while True:
    send()
    receive()
```

Is it possible constantly run message receival process in the background without having to wait for user input each time?

Answer (score 1):

You could use threads or async. In the example below I used thread to run a function that prints a message ("hey") in the terminal while the program waits for the user input.

```
from threading import Thread

class Receiver(Thread):
  def __init__ (self, msg):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.message = msg

  def run(self):
    while(True):
      print(self.message)
      delay(1)

a = Receiver("heey")
a.start()
a = input("write your message")
```